# MacBook Air A1237 Recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, recovery

I replaced the hard drive on my Macbook Air. When I press the option key while powering on it takes me to a screen where I select a WiFi network and nothing else is on the screen. I connect to WiFi and then nothing happens. There Are no other options. What should i do?

I have also tried the same procedure with the old disk, but the same strange thing happens.

It connects to the WiFi network but that's all.

Comment: Have you tried Command Option R to force Internet Recovery mode? You'll still need to connect to WiFi, and then an animated globe icon will appear if it has booted into that mode.

Comment: you mean instead of booting while pressing option button? or after i boot with option button and then press command option r?

Comment: Boot holding Command Option R instead of Option by itself. Sorry for the lack of clarity in my previous comment.

Comment: just tried that. i get a flashing question mark meaning there is no boot option available!

Comment: A1237 is a 2008 MacBook Air. The Internet Recovery has been introduced with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion in July 2011.

Comment: If you replaced the hard drive there is nothing on it. You need a bootable USB with OS X on it.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Air (from early 2008) does neither have a Recovery HD by default nor an Internet Recovery.  You would need to install the original OS with the medium you received with your computer (Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard) or if you either have the disc or a USB stick version of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, you can install that as well (disc version will require either a USB SuperDrive or a second Mac with an optical drive you can share). Once done, you can at least use your computer again already.

If you, however, want to reinstall Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, you will first have 10.6 Snow Leopard installed and fully updated (see above what that will require). Otherwise, you would need a USB stick with the Lion Installer on it to bypass installing Leopard or Snow Leopard.

Comment: can i use an external dvd drive?

Comment: I'm not sure about third party USB DVD drives, but the Apple SuperDrive (which is a DVD drive as well) will definitely work.

Comment: @IoannisValeris, yes.  You can use any external DVD Drive.  My suggestion is to get a USB stick and put the OS X installer on that.   It is much more convenient than a DVD (and much faster)

Comment: Well, here is an update. Now, holding down option key and power on, does nothing. i can no longer access the WiFi selection key. don't know why. i followed a guide to create a bootable usb to install os x. i used a usb drive which previously formated to GPT using diskpart. then, using transmac i built the installation. But when i insert it to my mac and powering on, i get a white screen and a stop sign in the middle...

Comment: Since I don't know the guide you used, I cannot say what went wrong there.  To create a USB clone, I personally would start up from the Install disc,  then use Disk Utility to create one partition on the USB drive and then "Restore" the disc onto the USB drive partition.  That would not only copy its contents, but also format the USB drive partition in the proper fashion. If that does not do the trick, just use the disc itself to install Mac OS X 10.6.  Once installed and updated, install Mac OS X 10.7, if you want (or need).

Comment: Once Mac OS X 10.7 Lion is installed, you can use the [OS X Recovery Disk Assistant v1.0](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) to create a bootable USB drive.  If you still have another Mac with Mac OS X 10.7.x installed, you can also create the bootable USB drive using that Mac.  Just make sure it is Mac OS X 10.7 and not Mac OS X 10.8 or later as your MacBook Air will not be able to install Mac OS X 10.8 or later.